# Callback for when a UIWebView is closed in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, callback

In my app, I load a WebView and then from that load another in an embedded browser. I would like to execute a function on the first WebView when the user closes the embedded browser. Anyone know how I can achieve this? What I need ideally (and believe does not exist) is a callback function when a user closes an embedded browser.

Thanks,
Neha.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd like to do something similar

Answer (score -1):

Basic concept is listed below

```
// set up notification for when embedded browser is closed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
          selector:@selector(myMethod) 
          name:@"embeddedBrowserClosed" object:nil];

// post notification when browser is closed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
          postNotificationName:@"embeddedBrowserClosed"]
```

See more here at this [Blog Posting](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/02/nsnotifications-broadcasting-mechanism.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Pardon me for the noob question but where do I put the postNotificationName call? I'm doing this within the first webview     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]; 
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: I think that the answer is out of context here.